Help finding a short story about a man who goes to a psychiatrist, who then acquires his delusion (or reality; the story isn't clear on that point)
I read a short story in the 1960's about a man who went to a psychiatrist or psychologist because of a recurring delusion. The delusion was that he has a secret room where women adore him and get him anything he wants, often without him even asking; they just know what he wants. The patient wants to spend more time in the real world, but keeps being drawn into the secret room.
The psychiatrist "cures" the patient, but then finds that he is seeing the secret room and starts spending all of his time there. Is it real or a delusion?
I have no idea how well it was written (I was in junior high), but it was an intriguing idea, and I'd like to find out if it's as good as I remembered.

IIRC, there's a similar scenario but with a different delusion buried somewhere in The Martian Chronicles.

Sounds vaguely like a story called Narapoia (the opposite of paranoia)

@JiminyCricket. I can't recall any similar scenario from The Martian Chronicles. Unless by "similar scenario" you just mean "man goes to a psychiatrist"? There is a Martian psychiatrist in "The Earth Men". Is that what you mean? The one where the explorers from Earth get locked up in a Martian insane asylum? Or is there some other Martian Chronicle which actually resemble's the OP's story?

That's right, man goes to psychiatrist (to finally get someone to listen to him about being the second expedition) who locks him away as dangerous and potentially infectious. The psychiatrist finally kills himself because he thinks he's infected by the man's delusion (he too can see/touch the space-craft). @user14111 An echo of the OP's story, but with a different delusion.
